# React Native DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, device

I'm trying to run a React-Native application on my Android device which is a Huawei Honor 7, the device is connected to the pc through USB and I'm running it through command with: `react-native run-android` why am I getting this error?

[image]

Comment: Close the currently running package manager and the app. `react-native start` in terminal and rerun the app from device/simulator.

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh didn't work =(

Comment: than delete the app and re install :), and make sure you are running the packager from the right folder

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh done that too, multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/176
Looks like you just need to reinstall `node_modules`

Comment: I tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` in the project folder in command but it says that rm is not recognized as a command

Comment: Are you on Windows? Just close all packagers that are running. Manually delete `node_modules` folder. Than run `npm install` and `react-native run-android`. Window version of `rm -rf` is `rd /s /q "path"`